# find rogue code (text outside of any tags) and wrap them as they appear

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-selectors

I'm creating a script to filter some forum output which involves selecting everything between adjacent `<p>`'s, the number of "p" changes every time. And contents in between p tag-pairs could be nothing to anything. Some thing like this:

```
    <p><a href="x">...ABC...</a></p>

    <<<<<<<< Beginning of what I want >>>>>>>>

    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <font title="...">...</font>
    sometext without any tag<br>  <-----This cannot be selected by jQuery, help needed here
    <a href="...">...</a>
    //[0..N] more tags

    <<<<<<<< End of what I want >>>>>>>>

    <p><a href="x+1">...ABC...</a></p>
    [0..N] more "p"'s with similar pattern ("p" with random url in "a")
```

Then I want to wrap those rogue codes (untagged text) together with its neighbors into some div so that I can process them later. Like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="1">
        <p><a href="x">...ABC...</a></p>

    <! Beginning of what I want >

        <fieldset>...</fieldset>
        <font title="...">...</font>
        sometext without any tag<br>
        <a href="...">...</a>
        //[0..N] more tags

    <! End of what I want >
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <p><a href="x+1">...ABC...</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        //something or nothing
    </div>
    //something or nothing
</div>
```

The tricky part is to find out which part they belong and move them in to that part. As they are not in any div or even any tag. I tried with this approach:

```
    var ps = $("p:contains('ABC')");
    ps.each(function(){
        if(!($(this).next()[0])){
            return true;
        }
        var me = $(this);
        var pa = me.parent().contents();
        var nx = me.nextAll("p:contains('ABC')").first()
        var i0 = pa.index(me);
        var i1 = pa.index(nx);
        if (i1 > i0) {
            var elements = pa.slice(i0, i1);
            elements.each(function(){
                //Do something
            });
        }
    });
```

But the text is always left out. I think it's jquery could not select anything without a tag? What should I do to get it to work?

Comment: *"...find rouge code..."* The code is showing up in [red](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouge)? ;-)

Comment: No. My post was not clear. I just edited it. Those text are outside of any tag. I need to put it into the tags I created while not changing the appearance of the page.

Comment: @ ericire: It was just a silly joke ("rouge" = "red" in French and is also sometimes used as a color name in English; you probably meant "rogue").

Comment: Yeah it should be rogue. I didn't know how to spell it.. But you got it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kTVQY/1/

I don't think you will mind it having in div!

```
jQuery('div.find').each(function(){
    $("*").each( function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    plugin(this);
});

function plugin(node) {
    var next;

    if (node.nodeType === 1) {

        if (node = node.firstChild) {
            do {
                next = node.nextSibling;
                plugin(node);
            } while(node = next);
        }

    } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            alert(node.data);
    }

}
```

Comment: But the output HTML is empty? I would like to have it look exactly(or almost) the same as what it looked before except properly wrapped. I mean what should I do with node.data in the else case? I can wrap it but how do I know where it was?

Comment: hey i will do it more tommorow!